# Is it possible to store images as key and some contact info corresponding to that key in a database?

Tags: image, nosql, key-value-store

I need to create a database where I can store images and some contact information related to the images. Is it possible to have this arrangement stored as key-value pairs, where images act as key and the information act as values?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have this arrangement stored as key-value pairs, where images act as key and the information act as values?

If this really is what you want, it sounds viable. If your key-value-store uses a `string` as *key*, you can [Base64 encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) the image, but a SHA-hash is probably preferred. And add what you want as *value* e.g. json-formatted metadata information.

The problem what that layout is how to *lookup* things in your key-value-store, since you need the *image* to do the lookup.